# Using IValueConverter For A Bound TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a textbox in a ListView:

```
<GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Password,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Can someone give me the code to convert the text to "•" and in-code behind back again to the original text (using IValueConverter or any other method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use passwordBox control:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassword" />
```

And if binding is your problem then you can implement an Interface in the View which have a method say "GetCredential()" and in the ViewModel you can get the password value and can do the further Authentication.